Jenkins throws compliation errors for Discord Notifier Webhook URL in declerative pipeline
My decelerative pipeline has a stage that sends out a message to a Discord Channel using a webhook. The script in my Jenkins file that does this is as follows.
stage('DiscordMessage') {
  steps {
    discordSend {
      webhookURL: "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/123456789012345678/me-3_LacrufNcvKg-U",
      discordSend description: 'Status of my Project',
      footer: '',
      image: '',
      link: env.BUILD_URL,
      result: currentBuild.currentResult,
      scmWebUrl: '',
      thumbnail: '',
      title: JOB_NAME
    }
  }
}

The jenkinsfile is checked into SCM on GIT. When I run the job on Jenkns the SCM checkout is performed successfully. However it throws compilation errors.
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 101: unexpected token: https://discord.com/api/webhooks/123456789012345678/me-3_LacrufNcvKg-U @ line 101, column 27.
                 webhookURL: "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/123456789012345678/me-3_LacrufNcvKg-U",

This script was generated using the Jenkins Snippet Generator. The generator had the Webhook as the last parameter. With this Jenkins would throw the following compilation error
Missing required parameter: "webhookURL" @ line 100, column 13.
               discordSend {
               ^

So I made a few changes based on example provided on the Jenkins Discord Notifier Plugins Page https://plugins.jenkins.io/discord-notifier/. I changed Single quotes to double quotes, moved the webhook URL as the first parameter etc. I still get the compliation error. Any idea what could be wrong.

I don't understand the reason for a downvote. That script was genereted by the Jenins Script Generator.

Parentheses () and curly braces {} are not freely interchangeable in Groovy :). It's:
discordSend(
      webhookURL: "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/123456789012345678/me-3_LacrufNcvKg-U",
      discordSend description: 'Status of my Project',
      footer: '',
      image: '',
      link: env.BUILD_URL,
      result: currentBuild.currentResult,
      scmWebUrl: '',
      thumbnail: '',
      title: JOB_NAME
)

